# jQuery TimePicker and jQueryUI 1.8.7 conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the time picker control from the following link: http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/timepicker.html

It works super fine, but once I reference the *jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css* I can't get it to work.
Do you know what may be the problem?
I need the *jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css* because I want to use the standard date picker on the same page.

Thank you

EDIT:

Problem is in *jquery.ui.core.css*, line 14:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute !important; clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px); }
```

When I comment this line than everything works fine. Is this line really important? :)

EDIT #2:

Better solution is to edit that line:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, removing that line should be fine... I'm not sure *exactly* what it does, but it's definitely not critical.  Likely something to do with a handicap reader or something.

**FYI:** Try specifying the `scope` of your theme.  It might mitigate this problem all together.  You can apply the theme to certain selectors.  This would allow you to simply add `.your-class` to your datepicker markup and it will be the only component styled.  This feature is found on the right hand column of the theme builder [**download section**](http://jqueryui.com/download/). *See screenshot*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I specify the CSS scope, than I'm able to use datepicker and timepicker at the sime time. But now I can't load the Theme :(

Comment: Solution for above problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811545/how-to-apply-css-theme-to-only-a-specific-jquery-ui-element/2669919#2669919

Answer (score 1):

The control has been updated and does not conflict with jquery-ui 1.8.7 css any more. The ui-helper-hidden-accessible class has been removed from the control.